# Error with C# Web crawler

Tags: c#, web-crawler

Can some one please assist me with this webcrawler, I keep getting the error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ISt' to 'string.

This error is in line where it is `String Links = GetNewLinks(Rstring);`, can someone please help, here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;



namespace Crawler
{
public partial class Crawler : Form
{
    String Rstring;

    public Crawler()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        WebRequest myWebRequest;
        WebResponse myWebResponse;
        String URL = txt1.Text;

        myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL);
        myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream streamResponse = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        Rstring = sreader.ReadToEnd();
        String Links = GetNewLinks(Rstring);

        txt2.Text = Rstring;
        txt3.Text = Links;
        sreader.Close();
        streamResponse.Close();
        myWebResponse.Close();

    }

    public ISet<string> GetNewLinks(string content)
    {
        Regex regexL = new Regex("(?<=<a\\s*?href=(?:'|\"))[^'\"]*?(?=(?:'|\"))");

        ISet<string> newLinks = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var match in regexL.Matches(content))
        {
            if (!newLinks.Contains(match.ToString()))
                newLinks.Add(match.ToString());
        }

        return newLinks;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well yes - you have a method returning a set of strings, and you're trying to assign it to a variable of type `String`. How did you *expect* that to work?

Comment: its not home work, its a personal project i am working on...

Answer (score 0):

`GetNewLinks()` returns a set of strings (`ISet<String>`), not one only. So if you want to assign to a single string (`String Links`) then you have to select a string from the set, e.g. using [`First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb291976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).